# Is there an actual use for the "Sound Waves HUD" chip?

Tags: nier-automata

I bought all of the HUD chips at the beginning of my first playthrough and immediately equipped them. Most give useful HUD features like an EXP bar or health meter, but I've been unable to figure out what the Sound Wave HUD chip does for me.

[image: sound waves HUD chip]

It seems to just display a small sound analyzer that analyzes the BGM. I've had it equipped for over 20 hours of playtime and haven't noticed it do anything special other than this. Is this really all it does? It seems absolutely pointless to have equipped if this is the case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from analyzing the BGM and looking cool, the HUD Sound Waves chip serves *one* other purpose. According to posts like the one in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75103746), it helps you find a specific Pod in the desert:

> There's an item in the desert (pod C) that emits a high-pitched sound when you're close to it so it's easier to find. The sound display detects this noise, giving a hint to people who can't hear it (or hear poorly in general, or people like me who thought my speakers were dying instead of thinking it was an actual game sound).

This is backed up in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168677-nier-automata/75081293), as well:

> I believe it's meant to help those who have a handicap with their hearing.
>
> There is an thing (a pod) in the desert that can be found through a sound it makes. Not everyone can hear it.

If you've already found this Pod or are confident in your hearing abilities, there appears to be no other purpose to this chip other than being a BGM analyzer.

Comment: There are at least two of such pods. While playing through a later story route, I came across the same type of sound-based pod in the factory. It is also worth noting that these are not actually Pods, but Pod Programs. There are only 3 Pods in the game. The additional 2 are found in other ways.

Comment: Man, when you say high-pitched, that's no exaggeration - I just found the desert pod yesterday, and I seriously thought my speakers were broken. It's a very high, screeching noise, kind of like nails on a chalkboard. I think it's high enough pitch that people with hearing problems might not hear it, but if your hearing is healthy it's almost painful to listen to. Not sure why they thought that was a good idea as opposed to, say, a beeping noise.

Comment: @MageXy I don't recall actually hearing it honestly, but maybe I was blaming my TV too. I'll have to go look in my newer file to see if I notice it. Hope you enjoy the game other than the bleeding ears! (It's my favorite)

Comment: I'm also playing the PC port, so that might have something to do with it. The game's otherwise really nice - combat is fluid and impactful, music is fantastic, and the story so far is *very* captivating.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is related to when normal enemy robots are talking. You will not hear them talk if you don't have this equipped.

Comment: This is not true. I didn’t have this equipped the entire time I played my second time and they *all* talked.