# Unknown quest area in desert

Tags: nier-automata

I am currently in part 2 (playing as 9S), and there is red area - like for quests, in the desert. But it does not relate to any of my active quests. [image: map qith weird quest] It appeared also during the part 1 (playing as 2B). I wandered through that location many times, even with dynamic sensor active, and found nothing. What is it and why does it appear? Is it some part of weird quest? Or will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this. It related to [finding Pod C](https://nierautomata.wiki.fextralife.com/Pod+C), if you find it, the red area will disappear from the map. 
Not that dynamic sensor does not help you here and you just have to watch the ground to find the pod.

Comment: Seems you can also [listen for it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/303205).